# Why does this "Slow network detected..." log appear in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, font-face

I noticed this `info log` began to appear in Google Chrome Dev (Version 55.0.2883.18 dev) and I can't imagine why.

> Slow network is detected. Fallback font will be used while loading: http://font-path.extension`

It appears on all websites that use `font-face`, even on local pages and Chrome extensions.

[image: Print screen of a local website]

Comment: ChromeDevTools [tweeted](https://twitter.com/ChromeDevTools/status/923956064826966016) that they're looking into this issue.

Comment: In my case my page is not using google web fonts. The "WOT: Web Of Trust" extension is injecting code to load fonts. You can check which extension is doing it, in the developer tools network tab. Find the offending font request and click in the "initiator" column to see source. Then look up the tree on the left to see what extension the file is in.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Showing on console: Slow network is detected. Fallback font will be used while loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42342133/showing-on-console-slow-network-is-detected-fallback-font-will-be-used-while-l)

Comment: enable-webfonts-intervention-v2 is not in my chrome flags: 64.0.3282.167

Comment: This doesn't necessarily mean your network is slow. It appears for many users on their localhost dev machines also e.g. [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/psiturk/CJax-rQUHhY)

Comment: I can't believe this is still an issue in 2020 in Chrome v81, when serving fonts from localhost.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

This means the network is slow, and Chrome is replacing a web font (loaded with a `@font-face` rule) with a local fallback.

By default, the text rendered with a web font is invisible until the font is downloaded ([“flash of invisible text”](https://css-tricks.com/fout-foit-foft/)). With this change, the user on a slow network could start reading right when the content is loaded instead of looking into the empty page for several seconds.

- Related Chrome issue: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=578029. (A change enabling this behavior for 3G connections landed in September; this should be the reason you got the message.)
- Related source code: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/third_party/+/master/WebKit/Source/core/css/RemoteFontFaceSource.cpp#74

Comment: Can I disable this notification?

Comment: Like Acauã Montiel commented above, you can disable this at chrome://flags/#enable-webfonts-intervention-v2

Comment: I think the notification is kinda useful for development. The issue is when Chrome shows it for every single extensions installed in the same console log, so much noise. What's the point of showing it for extensions?

Comment: any reason this message stil appears even though the font is loaded from memory/disk cache? Could this mean there's a delay in loading the font from cache as well?

Comment: I am running from localhost and getting the same error

Comment: Instead of disabled warnings and errors, Is there any solutions for load fonts from Cache, Retry to load fonts again?

Comment: Hide these messages by using this regex filter: `/^((?!Fallback font).)*$/`. Unlike other methods, this allows all other enabled message types to display.

Comment: Hmmm, that regex doesn't seem to work as expected: it hides some error messages too. Anyone able to use a negative lookahead regex to hide the "Fallback font" errors, while showing others?

Comment: @Robin if you're reloading page with devtools open the 'disable cache' option is enabled by default, if you go to network tab and uncheck it and reload the page the logs will not appear

Comment: Disabling the flag doesn't seem to be working on the Chrome 61.0.3163.91 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Surely my *local network* is not slow. Sounds like a bug in Chrome.

Comment: Surely my 100MBit internet is not slow. Sounds like a bug in Chrome.

Comment: Surely my local SSD is not slow. Sounds like a bug in Chrome.

Comment: Surely spitting out 200+ alerts for the same 5 fonts is not good usability.  Sounds like a bug in chrome.

Comment: Here's a bug report that may well be related if you've ever chosen "network throttling": https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=778477 Go and vote if you think it's related!

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and solution. I had same the issue and now I know to to fix.

Comment: It is ugly notification, why I need to know Chrome is replacing something? It disturbs javascript debugging.

Comment: I also got this running on localhost and the font file that caused the error is only 43kB in size. Surely it won't be slow in any situation. There is another font file I used at the same font folder that is 374kB and it never caused any error. I'm sure it's a bug in Chrome.

Answer (score 110):

I faced same issue for chrome build `61.0.3163.100` on MacOs Sierra with `localhost` as server. Chrome started logging this message when I changed network speed configuration to 3G fast/ 3G slow and again back to Online.

**Fix:**
When I tried selecting Offline mode and again Online mode, the logging issue disappeared. *(This fix may no work on some devices or versions)*

> **Update on 30th Jan 2018**

I updated google chrome to Version `64.0.3282.119 (Official Build) (64-bit)`, it seems this bug is fixed now.

Comment: Checking/unchecking the Offline mode toggle in the Network tab worked for me too — the fonts were being served from a dev server on localhost, so I didn't think it was really a "slow network" issue ;-) In my case I hadn't even been messing with other speed configurations or anything…weird. Thanks for finding and sharing this workaround!

Comment: Thanks for sharing this workaround - worked for me too!

I couldn't find a bug report for this, so I've filed one: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=778477

Comment: It did not work for Chrome 61.0.3163.91 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: This seems like a safer workaround than changing a flag, but it didn't work on 62.0.3202.89 on MacOS Sierra

Comment: Worked like a charm. These warnings was bugging me like crazy since I couldn't see any reason for it being slow :)

Comment: This worked _briefly_ for me with Version 62.0.3202.94 on MacOS Sierra, but quickly reverted :(

Comment: Fixed for me on Chrome Version 63.0.3239.132. Thanks

Comment: This still worked for me (with a refresh between check / uncheck the offline within Network tab) in Chrome version 66.0.3359.139 on Windows 7.

Comment: Worked for me on version 68.0.3440.84, but only intermittently. When working in Angular and on every save/recompile of files the problem comes back when the page reloads.

Comment: Using Chrome 68.0.3440.106 I noticed the Audit tab of dev tools had Simulated 3G toggled. I don't remember turning the setting on but going back to No Throttling fixed the issue.

Answer (score 79):

**EDIT: This is not working with latest version of 63.0+**

I was able to disable it using help from one of above comments, go to

**`chrome://flags/#enable-webfonts-intervention-v2`**

The trick is to also disable the "*Trigger User Agent Intervention for WebFonts loading always*" option just below that as well.

[image]

Comment: This actually does not answer OP's question of "Why that log came in Console in the first place". You can edit your answer if you know that.

Comment: In chrome 63 there isn't such option and this bug appeared to me.

Comment: @MortezaZiaeemehr, It's unfortunate. The whole interface is changed now. And I am not facing the issue now.

Comment: I have this message in 66.0.3359.139. But there is not option `chrome://flags/#enable-webfonts-intervention-v2`

Comment: for new chrome versions disable `chrome://flags/#align-font-display-auto-lcp`

Answer (score 45):

In my case, it was AdBlock Plus extension for Google chrome. Turned it off and it worked perfectly.

Comment: In my case it was "WOT: Web of Trust" extension.  I don't see why the thing needs to load its own special fonts, it should just use whatever default font.

Comment: Turning off AdBlock because of seeing the error and continue watching ADs? Perfect solution /sarcasm

Comment: This behavior can also be because of poorly written JavaScript/jQuery code. If you have a function called but not declared, it can happen. If you are copying/pasting your code and removing some of the functions not used, be extra careful.

Comment: Although it is already 2023, I still face the issue. And then I saw your answer and turned ABP off for impacted hostname (in my case it is `localhost`). Now the warning is finally gone. Awesome!

Comment: Recently Adblock Plus and Adblock has have bugs so I am sure that this is the issue. People thought that it was Youtube slowing down their browser (and yes they have been), but bugs have been reported on both adblocking sites. So my solution is switch to Brave browser.

Answer (score 41):

if you can access to css of this extension, simply add **`font-display:block;`** on font-face definition or send feedback to developer of this extension:)

```
@font-face {
  font-family: ExampleFont;
  src: url(/path/to/fonts/examplefont.woff) format('woff'),
       url(/path/to/fonts/examplefont.eot) format('eot');
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: block;
}
```

Comment: This is the proper way to resolve the issue, set the font-display property to any value that is not 'auto'. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/font-display#The_font_display_timeline

Comment: You can fix it globally by adding `* {font-display: block;}` to your css file.

Comment: `font-display` can only be used in a `@font-face` declaration. So `* {font-display: block;}` will not work as expected.

Comment: Thank you! Fixed! Why is it like this?

Comment: How about `font-display: swap;` ?

Answer (score 14):

I hide this by set console setting

`Console settings` -> `User messages only`

Comment: @AamirRizwan Watch out. This setting will hide `Error` message too.

Comment: This answer is identical to the one by @David Yew, apart from having a number of undesired side effects

Answer (score 10):

Goto chrome://flags/#enable-webfonts-intervention-v2 and set it to disabled

It’s due to a bug in Chrome with their latest API for ‘network speed’. Hope it will be fixed in the next version

Answer (score 9):

I have network throttling disabled but started to get this error today on a 75mb/s business connection...

To fix it in my build of Chrome 60.0.3112.90 (Official Build) (64-bit) I opened the DevTools then navigated to the DevTools Settings then ticked 'Log XMLHttpRequests', unticked 'User messages only' and 'Hide network messages'

Answer (score 4):

I just managed to make the filter regex work: `/^((?!Fallback\sfont).)*$/`.

Add it to the filter field just above the console and it'll hide all messages containing `Fallback font`.

You can make it more specific if you want.

Comment: I think I am gonna go with this solution. I think going selecting certain messages like "User Messages Only" is not recommended at all. One can easily miss the errors or warning thrown by your web app.

Answer (score 3):

If your developing an app that uses google fonts and want to ensure your users do not see these warnings. A possible solution ([detailed here](http://www.thephphero.com/how-to-host-google-fonts-locally/)) was to load the fonts locally.

I used this solution for an application which at times has slow internet (or no internet access) but still serves pages, This assumes your app uses Google fonts and updates to these fonts are not critical. Also assume that using ttf fonts are appropriate for your application [WC3 TTF Font Browser Support](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_fonts.asp).

Here is how I accomplished locally serving fonts:

### Go to https://fonts.google.com/ and do a search for your fonts

### [image: search]

### Add your fonts

### [image]

### Download them

### [image]

### Place them in site root

### [image]

### Add them to your @font file

### [image]

Answer (score 3):

1. No, this doesn't mean network is slow.
2. No, this is not only false warning.

I have this problem on angular web applications after replace link https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons in index.html to integrated version (npm install .... material-icons...). This works, but sometimes web application show that warning.

When warning is shown icons are not rendered for approximately 1 second, so user see badly rendered icons.

I don't have solution yet.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same errors with fontawesome's fonts. 
Then I downloaded the lastest fontawesome's fonts and replace to the old fonts.
And the errors are gone.

Comment: Could you please describe more ? how did you do this ?

Comment: Hmm.. I think that could solve my problem.. lemme try

Comment: well for me.. <i class="fas fa-plus-square" ></i>  wasn't working .. i changed it to just fas fa-plus

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to disable this is uncheck the warnings in the chrome dev tools

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's a pretty bad idea.

Comment: @JamesGentes you are correct and this is not a permanent solution. Sometimes it is better to just turn it off if you are debugging and don't want to see hundreds of 'Slow network is detected...'

Comment: same you could say just close the browser and you will not see it too.

Comment: @NikitaChernykh That is not at all the same. It's not. Really.

Comment: This indeed disable this message, but also all other warnings whom might be useful.

Comment: This answer is identical to the one by @David Yew, apart from having a number of undesired side effects

Answer (score 1):

you can click 'console settings', and check then box 'Use messages only', after that those messages won't show again.

[image]

Comment: This answer is identical to the one by @David Yew, apart from having a number of undesired side effects

Answer (score 1):

Updating to the latest version of Chrome (63.0.3239.84) via Help -> About fixed it for me.

(actually, I did had to switch to Offline and back to Online in the Network tab of developers tools to make the last errors go away.)

Answer (score 1):

As soon as I disabled the DuckDuckGo Privacy Essentials plugin it disappeared. Bit annoying as the fonts I was serving was from localhost so shouldn't be anything to do with a slow network connection.

Answer (score 0):

Right mouse сlick on Chrome Dev. Then select filter. And select source of messages.

Comment: Still not good solution compared to disabling that specific message inside chrome settings. For example I am using SSR and source of this alert may be same as from actual application, therefore it also disables my desired logs. Other than that, there might be many sources and you would need to filter many of them.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed if I use the 'woff' version of the font alone, I got this latency warning message. But if I add the 'ttf' version, the warning disapear. As I'am using a local web application, I made a tradeoff as of the size of font file.

```
font-face {
  font-family: Rakaba;
  src: url(../assets/font/web/Rakaba-Bold.woff) format('woff'),
        url(../assets/font/Rakaba-Bold.ttf) format('ttf');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using google fonts
change who

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Almarai:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

to

```
<link rel="preconnect" as="style" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" as="style" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Almarai:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

You add the following

```
as="style"
```

I hope it helps