# Showing on console: Slow network is detected. Fallback font will be used while loading

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, fonts, webfonts

what can I do in this case?
I'm seeing this on my console when ran on the browser the AngularJS App:

*Slow network is detected. Fallback font will be used while loading:* `/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2`

I also see the fonts changing while loading.

Comment: disabling the flag under `chrome://flags/#enable-webfonts-intervention-v2` will prevent this appearing.

Comment: disabling the flag under chrome://flags/#enable-webfonts-intervention-v2 not working in chrome version >61

Comment: Most of the answers below are copied form here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40143098/why-does-this-slow-network-detected-log-appear-in-chrome

Comment: This is a fail safe for chrome to speed up their chromium engine. that way if your website is loading slowly then local font will be used to show your website than later when everything is loaded your original font will appears. as mentioned you can go ahead and disable it `chrome://flags/#enable-webfonts-intervention-v2` and you won't see this anymore

Comment: It is no longer working. There is no flag for enable-webfonts-intervention-v2. So issue reappeared. How can we resolve it now?

Comment: @FaizanRupani this issue is coming even with the fonts available locally or cached. This message is coming even for extensions loading custom fonts available locally within.

Comment: I'm not seeking a way to turn it off which seems to be what all the "answers" are doing. I'm seeking to understand what network process triggers this and how to resolve that condition.

Answer (score 36):

Setting the following chrome flag to  **`Unknown`** will prevent that message appearing on dev-console :

```
chrome://flags/#force-effective-connection-type
```

[image]

**ᴛᴇꜱᴛᴇᴅ ᴏɴ**
Google Chrome
Version **63.0.3239.84**

Comment: ... and if you're using an earlier version of chrome then probably check out my comment under OP.

Comment: THIS IS THE ANSWER for newer versions of Chrome. Thanks!

Comment: Works on Version 67.0.3396.62 (Official Build) (64-bit) (Windows 10). This is the right answer for 2018.

Answer (score 11):

Same issue in localhost server.

But if you don't want to see these messages in log:

On the `chrome tools` => `console settings` => checked on User messages only

Comment: Just to clarify this, open up Dev Tools, select the Console tab, and click the gear icon on the upper right. Then select "User messages only".

Comment: This not only disable this specific message but also all other useful messages (warnings, errors to name some)

Comment: This answer has a number of undesired side effects, as already noted by @tomsihap

Answer (score 7):

Simply add **`font-display`** to all css font-face definitions to remove error from console.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: ExampleFont;
  src: url(/path/to/fonts/examplefont.woff) format('woff'),
       url(/path/to/fonts/examplefont.eot) format('eot');
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the multiple frameworks that are been used. You can ignore it. It does not create any problems. You can just remove things from console only.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fail safe for chrome to speed up their chromium engine. that way if your website is loading slowly then local font will be used to show your website than later when everything is loaded your original font will appears. as mentioned you can go ahead and disable it `chrome://flags/#enable-webfonts-intervention-v2` and you won't see this anymore

Answer (score 0):

I am facing same issue.To resolve this issue simply inspect the browser page -> goto console -> On right top open console setting -> select/check users messages only option it will disappear these slow network logs

Answer (score 0):

This browser-independent JavaScript solution prevents these logs and [FOUT-FOIT-FOFT](https://css-tricks.com/fout-foit-foft/) by making the user wait until the font has been downloaded.

In client JavaScript use [fontfaceobserver](https://github.com/bramstein/fontfaceobserver) to detect if the font is loaded, and do not show the markup using that font until the font is loaded.

How not to show the markup depends on which stack you use.

Answer (score 0):

I FIXED THIS ERROR BY TURNING OFF THE  **AD BLOCKER TOOL**

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by modifying my database, it turns out that twas a server error not on the code or in the flags, hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

In Chrome type the URL and enter `chrome://flags/#disable-accelerated-2d-canvas` we will see new version of User Agent Intervention for WebFonts loading then disable it, the problem will get resolved

Answer (score -1):

```
chrome inspect tools -> console setting -> check "User messages only"
```

---

To hide these messages can do  followsing steps :

1. Just open **inspect** the browser page
2. Click on **console** tab
3. On right top open **console settings**
4. Check **users messages only** option

It will hide all **slow network** console messages.
But keep in mind, It will only hide those messages not resolve the issue.

FYI :

[image: FYI]

Answer (score -2):

**I am happy with this meta tag.**

```
<meta content='IE=Edge;chrome=35+' https-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'/>
```