# Slow network is detected. Fallback font will be used while loading

Tags: google-chrome, font-awesome, console.log, fallback

Am getting `Slow network is detected. Fallback font will be used while loading:` on google chrome console

Comment: Duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40143098/why-does-this-slow-network-detected-log-appear-in-chrome

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does this "Slow network detected..." log appear in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40143098/why-does-this-slow-network-detected-log-appear-in-chrome)

Comment: May be...But i am not getting appropriate solution

Comment: So explain your situation so we can help you more; With only the error we cannot help you more !

Comment: "Slow network is detected. Fallback font will be used while loading: http://localhost:54721/Fonts/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0" is it a font issue or coding issue or browser issue ? how can i fix it permanently ? without hiding it form console.

Answer (score 3):

Simply add **`font-display:block;`** on all font-face definition.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: ExampleFont;
  src: url(/path/to/fonts/examplefont.woff) format('woff'),
       url(/path/to/fonts/examplefont.eot) format('eot');
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[click here for get solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6N4g.png)

**Remove your all   unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;**

Comment: Add some description here.

Comment: @Billa Just download all fonts manually and add in your project. Remove all unicode range from your css font file.